# How to execute a kubectl (k8s) command in all clusters?

Tags: kubectl

I want to get all pods with a specific label in all contexts.

What I have to do now is to iterate the contexts found in `kubectl config get-contexts`:

```bash
kgp --context [CONTEXT] -n my-namespace -l app=my-app
```

Is there an equivalent of `all-namespaces` but for contexts?

Comment: Nowhere mentioned in [offical doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-and-finding-resources) that we can get the pods from all contexts. The best way is as you mentioned you need to loop through the context and get the pods and save into a file for the full list.